# PHP gettext translation is not working

Tags: php, gettext

I need to translate my site to Tamil. This is my code:

```
$locale = "ta_IN";

putenv("LANG=".$locale);
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);

$domain = "ta_IN";
echo bindtextdomain($domain, "Locale");
bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, 'UTF-8');

textdomain($domain);

echo  _("Username");
```

And I have create `.mo` and `.po` files for the word `Username` and which is in the `/var/www/tamil/Locale/ta_IN/LC_MESSAGES/ta_IN.mo` and `ta_IN.po`, but it is not translating my site.

I have these questions and their accepted answers, but the solutions did not work for me:

- [PHP - GetText not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36834875/php-gettext-not-working)
- [How to debug gettext not working in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23170819/how-to-debug-gettext-not-working-in-php)
- [Gettext not working, no error messages, using php 5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917968/gettext-not-working-no-error-messages-using-php-5-3)

Answer (score 0):

If you're testing gettext on console (PHP-CLI) and not on a webserver, you have to reset the LANGUAGE environment variable too.

```
putenv("LANGUAGE=");
```